# Filtering a date range field with date range

Tags: python, django

React/Django app. I want to add a date range filter (flatpickr) to already existing filters for orders. Orders has a `period` field (how long the order is valid), which is a `DateRange` field. Via the flatpickr I select a date range, and if at least one day of the order period is in that selected date range, it should show up as a result.

ex. period: `DateRange(datetime.date(2021, 2, 11), datetime.date(2021, 3, 14), '[)')`

I have the filter ready in FE to accept the results from BE. But I'm not sure how to achieve this in the BE. As I'm fairly new to this, my ideas are limited, but currently have this:

```
...
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend, IsoDateTimeFilter, FilterSet
from rest_framework import filters, mixins, status
...

class OrderFilter(FilterSet):

    start_date = IsoDateTimeFilter(field_name="period", lookup_expr="gte")
    end_date = IsoDateTimeFilter(field_name="period", lookup_expr="lte")

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = {
            "status": ["in"],
            "client": ["exact"],
            "created_by": ["exact"],
        }

        ordering_fields = ["period", "client__name", "destination__name"]
        ordering = ["period"]
        custom_field_target_model = Order
```

I believe the closest thing I found, is [IsoDateTimeFromToRangeFilter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html?highlight=range#isodatetimefromtorangefilter), but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your field is `DateRangeField`, your [lookup expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/postgres/fields/ranges/) are limited. You can use the following options:

1. contains
2. contained_by
3. overlap

If your case to determine if period contains a specific date range (start_date, end_date), you can use it as:

```
Order.objects.filter(period__contains=(start_date, end_date))
```

you can also play with others if you wish.

The problem here is not the filter class, it is the field that you're trying to filter. If you keep period_start_date and period_end_date separately, you can filter the dates separately.
To filter a field with two inputs, you can use a [custom filter method](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#custom-generic-filtering) or you can [override](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters) the `get_queryset` method of your view.

Not: As @aberkb mentioned, you need to add "period" to fields.

Comment: I'm making the request from FE with react via API, using date range with two dates start_date and end_date. So I do not have the start_date and end_date actually available in the BE. With regards to your first suggestion to use `DateFromToRangeFilter`, I'm confused how I would use it in my case: to filter out orders which have at least 1 day from their validity period, overlapping with the filter date range. Could you please elaborate on this a bit more, or could you give a bit broader example?

Comment: Ideally, I'm looking something like this: 
`start_date = DateFromToRangeFilter(field_name="period__lower", lookup_expr="gte")`
`end_date = DateFromToRangeFilter(field_name="period__upper", lookup_expr="lte")`
Is there a way to make something similar work?

Comment: @perrer I've updated my answer, you can find useful information to determine a path to solve your problem.